# How do I use an external SMTP on Google Cloud Hosting Wordpress?

Tags: smtp, google-cloud-platform, wordpress, gmail

We have just setup a brand new Google Cloud Hosting account and installed a WP website on it.

We aren't using Gmail on it, as we want to connect outgoing mail via SMTP to our external Server.

When we do this on a non GCH account, it works.  But on it, it fails.  It times out.

So is this because GCH simply refuses to let you use an external one?  In which case - why would it do that?

If not, and we are forced to use Gmail, then how do we set that up?  We tried twice and failed.

Comment: Perhaps: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/ "Note: Port 25 is always blocked and can't be used, even through an SMTP relay using G Suite."

Comment: You will need an SMTP service that works on a port other than 25, and a Wordpress plugin that enables SMTP for email delivery.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports but port 25,so if you need to [send an email from the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#using_standard_email_ports) you have to use port 465 or 587.

GCP explecitely recomends using other [third-party tools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use) such as SendGrid, Mailgun, and Mailjet because they offer a free tier package, you can skip all that and connect your instance to [Gmail SMTP Relay Service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600). You will need a Google Account to connect (gmail or Gsuite).

Instructions to configure the Google Account are [HERE](https://help.frontapp.com/t/184yz6/configuring-g-suite-accounts-to-send-via-gmail-smtp-relay) , I tested sending emails from my MySQL server and Debian 9